# Intellij code formatting, keep /*package*/ on the same line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In some cases it makes a lot of sense to use package visibility for some methods.
By convention, we put a /* package */ comment in place of a modifier in order to make it clear that it is intentional :

```
/* package */ int getSpan() {  
    return mSpan; 
}
```

However, IntelliJ automatic formatting keeps putting this comment on a separate line ... for final methods only :/ .
Is there any way to configure the formatting so all occurrences of this comment are left on the same line ?

Comment: Have you tried to fiddle with those code style settings?

Comment: @Meo : yes but after 10 minutes of random fiddling, I decided that it was worth an SO post instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Intellij with my Scala code where the following:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global // TODO use own execution context
```

Was getting formatted into:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// TODO use own execution context
```

I managed to stop that happening by ticking `Comment at first column` under `Keep when formatting`:

[image]